# Modulenotefounderror; No module name cplex

Tags: python-3.x, cplex

Im working on my Mac and I just fixed the script.
Then I wanted to make an edit and no nothing seem to work anymore.

I get the error message;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lu.py", line 1, in 
    import cplex
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cplex'

I did not made the script and my knowledge about python is not much

When I want to start the script I use 
terminal -- cd (file location) pyzton3 lu.py

Anyone who can help me with this problem?

Comment: This is the script I try to run;

Comment: https://easyupload.io/bk4h8q

Comment: I assume you didn't install `cplex`; try `pip install cplex` in your terminal.

Comment: Also when I open my terminal I see the following; 
Last login: Sat Feb 15 23:14:53 on ttys000
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/annawickenkamp/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'

Comment: Well I used to run this scrip yesterday and it all worked like a charm. 
Also when I run pip Install culex I get

Comment: (-bash: pip: command not found)

Comment: Do you maybe need to activate some virtualenv or conda environment?

Comment: Maybe? is there a code to boot things up?

Comment: That's hard to say without knowing about how you have set up Python/Anaconda on your system. Did you activate some environment yesterday? (Check your .bash_history)

Comment: would a reinstall work?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the Python interpreter cannot find the CPLEX installation.
Usually this can be fixed by setting the `PYTHONPATH` variable correctly. Make sure that this variable contains the CPLEX Python libraries.

Assuming you are on Linux, you can do the following:

1. Find the CPLEX (or COS) installation folder.
2. Assuming this is `/path/to/COS` then you should have folder `/path/to/COS/cplex/python/` and in that folder different sub-directories that correspond to different Python versions.
3. Assuming you are running Python 3.6, execute the following in your shell: `export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/COS/cplex/python/3.6/x86-64_linux"` and then execute your script as before in the *same* terminal.